# c program doesn't work scanf char

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {

    struct cerchio c1, c2;
    float distanza;
    char k;

    //input del centro del primo cerchio
    printf("Enter the coordinate x of the first circle's center: ");
    scanf("%f", &c1.centro.x);
    printf("Enter the coordinate y of the first circle's center: ");
    scanf("%f", &c1.centro.y);

    //input del raggio del cerchio
    printf("Enter the circle's radius: ");
    scanf("%f", &c1.raggio);

    printf("The first circle's center is: (%.2f, %.2f)\n", c1.centro.x,      c1.centro.y);


    printf("Do you want to move this circle? y/n \n");
    //Here is the problem <-------------
    scanf("%s", &k); 

    if(k=='y'){
        moveCircle(&c1);
        printf("Now the circle's center is: (%.2f, %.2f)\n", c1.centro.x, c1.centro.y);
    }
}
```

In the scanf under the comment //here is the problem if i put %c the program end. The input doesn't work! If i put %s the program work perfectly. Why? I have declared the variable k char!

Comment: `char k[2];` .. `scanf("%1s", k);`.. `if(*k=='y'){`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, `if(*k=='y'){` is wrong, `k` is a `char`

Comment: @AlterMann see my comment **char k[2];**, `k` isn't a `char`.

Comment: Yes, but why change to an array, why not `scanf(" %c", &k);`?

Comment: for _If i put %s the program work perfectly._

Comment: Because of the trailling newline leaved by the previous `scanf`, but there is no need to switch to an array, just consume `\n` with `" %c"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
scanf("%s", &k);
```

should be

```
scanf(" %c", &k);
```

`%c` is the right format specifier for a character(`char`) while `%s` is used for strings. The space character behind `%c` skips all whitespace characters including none, until the first non-whitespace character as specified in the C11 standard:

> **7.21.6.2 The fscanf function**
>
> [...]
>
> 5. A directive composed of white-space character(s) is executed by reading input up to the first non-white-space character (which remains unread), or until no more characters can be read. The directive never fails

The reason why your program wouldn't wait for further input when you used `%c` is because there was a newline character(`\n`) prevailing in the standard input stream(`stdin`). Remembering pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> after entering data for each `scanf`? The newline character is **not** captured by the `scanf` with `%f`. This character is instead captured by the `scanf` with `%c`. This is why this `scanf` doesn't wait for further input.

As for why your other `scanf`s(with a `%f`) did not consume `\n` is because the `%f` skips whitespace characters as seen in the C11 standard:

> **7.21.6.2 The fscanf function**
>
> [...]
>
> 8. Input white-space characters (as specified by the `isspace` function) are skipped, unless the specification includes a `[`, `c`, or `n` specifier. <sup>284</sup>

As for why your program worked when you used is because you were lucky. Using `%s` instead of `%c` invokes [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). This is because `%s` matches a sequence of non-whitespace characters and adds a NUL-terminator at the end. Once a user enters anything, the first character is stored in `k` while the rest of the characters(if any) as well as the `\0` is written in an invalid memory location.

If you are currently thinking why the `%s` format specifier did not consume the `\n` is because it skips whitespace characters.

Comment: Thanks a lot! My informatics teacher who is an informatics and electronics engineer has not been able to explain it. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

use

```
scanf(" %c",&k);
```

Instead of

```
scanf("%s", &k); // %s is used for strings, Use %c for character variable.
```

for char variable  use " %c". and don't forget to keep space before %c `" %c"` , it will skips newline and whitespace characters.