# C program neglect in getting character after a string

Tags: c

Please give me a clear explanation for the below C program. It doesn't getting a character input after getting a string as an input .

**This doesn't works**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    char name[25],alpha;
    printf("Enter your name \n");
    scanf("%s",name);
    printf("\nEnter a character \n");
    scanf("%c",&alpha);
    printf("\nyour name is %s, and you entered %c",name,alpha);
    return 0; 
}
```

**This works**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    char name[25],alpha;
    printf("\nEnter a character \n");
    scanf("%c",&alpha);
    printf("Enter your name \n");
    scanf("%s",name);
    printf("\nyour name is %s, and you entered %c",name,alpha);
    return 0; 
}
```

why? what's the reason behind this execution. Thanks in advance

Comment: See [How to read / parse input in C? The FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178520/how-to-read-parse-input-in-c-the-faq), the part called "When *scanf() does not work as expected".

Comment: [doesn't work scanf char](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29557448/c-program-doesnt-work-scanf-char)

Comment: but  I used same things for 2nd program as you saw in 1st program, its working in perfect way as it should. Then why 1st program doesn't works

Comment: @MariSelvan Read the accepted answer of the duplicate question. It tells you why you get the result you do and how to fix it.

Comment: That's fine @Klas Lindback . But can you give me a solution to scan and print a character  after getting a string if possible .

Comment: @MariSelvan I did. Was anything unclear in the accepted answer to the linked queston?

Comment: Thanks @klas Lindback I'm too cleared .