# How to remove all repeated character in character array

Tags: arrays, c

I want to remove all the repeated characters from array. here is example.

```
"aabccdee"
```

```
"bd"
```

I'm doing this C language. use only array, loop, if,else(conditional statements) not using pointer.

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    char c[10];
    char com[10] = {0,};
    char result[10] = { 0, };
    int cnt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        scanf("%c", &c[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < 10; j++) {
            if (c[i] == c[j]) {
                com[i] = c[i];
                cnt++;
                printf("%c", com[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            if (com[i] != c[j]) {
                result[j] = c[j];
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%c", result[i]);
    }
}
```

I thought this

1. Make repeated array
2. Compare original array to repeated array
3. Output

But repeated array loop can't looping all original array.
How can I do remove all repeated character?

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow!
Okay first off, if you have something like ```"aba"``` is ```'a'``` to be removed?
Or do you only remove it if its duplicate like ```aab```

Comment: I want to remove all repeated elements. only left not repeated elements :)  @lmeguras

Comment: in two nested loops, check if there is another one of the value. of course, you shouldn't compare when i == j situation. then if there isn't another, add it.

Comment: if the order doesn't matter, you can sort your array and squash all duplicate after since they are all together after the sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not good SO policy to blatantly answer homework, but I rarely do it and thought this was an interesting task.  Certainly making no claims on efficiency, but it looks like it works to me.  As far as I can tell, the first and last cases are corner cases, so I handle those individually, and use a loop for everything in the middle.  If you're not allowed to use `strlen`, then you can roll your own or use some other method, that's not the primary focus of this problem (would be best to [`fgets`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) the string from a command line argument).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char source[] = "aabccdee";
    char result[sizeof(source)] = { 0 };

    unsigned resultIndex = 0;
    unsigned i = 0;

    // do this to avoid accessing out of bounds of source.
    if (strlen(source) > 1)
    {
        // handle the first case, compare index 0 to index 1. If they're unequal, save
        // index 0.
        if (source[i] != source[i+1])
        {
            result[resultIndex++] = source[i];
        }

        // source[0] has already been checked, increment i to 1.
        i++;
    
        // comparing to strlen(source) - 1 because in this loop we are comparing the
        // previous and next characters to the current. Looping from 1 to second-to-the-
        // last char means we stay in bounds of source
        for ( ; i < strlen(source) - 1; i++)
        {
            if (source[i-1] != source[i] && source[i] != source[i+1])
            {
                // write to result if curr char != prev char AND curr char != next char
                result[resultIndex++] = source[i];
            }
        }
    
        // handle the end. At this point, i == the last index of the string. Compare to
        // previous character. If they're not equal, save the last character.
        // 
        if (source[i] != source[i-1])
        {
            result[resultIndex] = source[i];
        }
    }
    else if (strlen(source) == 1)
    {
        // if source is only 1 character, then it's trivial
        result[resultIndex] = source[i];
    }
    else
    {
        // source has no length
        fprintf(stderr, "source has no length.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // print source and result
    printf("source = %s\n", source);
    printf("result = %s\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

Various outputs for `source`:

```
source = "aabccdee"
result = "bd"

source = "aaee"
result = 

source = "a"
result = "a"

source = "abcde"
result = "abcde"

source = "abcdee"
result = "abcd"

source = "aabcde"
result = "bcde"

source = "aaaaaaaaaaaabdeeeeeeee"
result = "bd"

source = ""
source has no length.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I already solve this problem to another way lol. But really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

first of all before we speak , you have to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29557448/c-program-doesnt-work-scanf-char)

you need to put a whitespace when scaning a char using scanf
so

```
        scanf("%c", &c[i]);
```

becomes

```
        scanf(" %c", &c[i]);
```

secondly your idea is kinda a messy as the result showed you're only handling cases and it doesn't continue verifying the whole array . you need to learn [how to shift an array to the right or left](https://codeforwin.org/2015/07/c-program-to-delete-duplicate-elements-from-array.html)

your issue later on that when you shift your table(not completely) you still print out of the size .

so bascilly in general your code should be something like this :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
  char c[10];
  int length=5;
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
       scanf(" %c", &c[i]);
   }
   int j,k,i;
   for(i=0; i<length; i++)
  {
      for(j=i+1; j<length; j++)
      {
          if(c[i] == c[j])
          {
                length--;
                for(k=j; k<length; k++)
                {
                   c[k] = c[k + 1];
                }
            j--;
        }
    }
  }
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        printf("%c", c[i]);
    }
}
```

you simply take one case and compare it to the rest , if it exists you shift from the position you find for the second time the element and so on

Comment: This code also working, but I want remove all repeated elements. Only left not repeated elements